# Page is not loading in the desired frame

Tags: java, html, struts, frame

i have a frame set where i load some pages like

```
Top ->   Header
Left ->  Menu
Right -> Data
```

but when i try to click on the menu the actual page has to be loaded in right side frame and it is not happening instead it is getting loaded in the left side frame and the menu is moved to right side.

I have given target="rightSideFrame" but still it is not getting.

i create link for the menu in java code and i use struts1.2.9 frame work

Following is my code snipet :

HTML :

```
<frameset border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" rows="64,*">
                    <frame border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" id="topFrame" name="topFrame" src="<%=resourcePath%>/common/header.jsp" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" noresize="noresize" scrolling="no">
                    <frameset border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" id="MainFrameSet" cols="209,*">
                            <frame noresize="noresize" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" id="leftFrame" name="leftFrame" src="<%=resourcePath%>/common/left_menu.jsp" scrolling="auto">
                            <frame border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" id="workFrame" name="workFrame" src="<%=resourcePath%>/common/WelcomePage.jsp" marginheight="7" marginwidth="7" noresize="noresize" scrolling="auto">
                    </frameset>
            </frameset>
```

and Menu link:

```
<a href=\"#\" target=\"workFrame\" onclick=\"getMenuRequest('"+model.getResource_name()+"','goToHome')\">"+model.getMenu_name()+"</a>
```

UPDATE :

and `getmenuRequest`

```
function getMenuRequest(actionName,methodName){
                       document.forms[0].action=actionName+".htm";
                       document.forms[0].method.value=methodName;
                       document.forms[0].submit();
                   }
```

Please help me to resolve this,

Regards

Comment: What does `getMenuRequest` do? Can you edit to include the source of this?

Comment: i have updated the post, Please have a look at it

Comment: You do not have a frame named `rightSideFrame` in the set, do you?

Comment: workframe the rightSideFrame, i just mentioned that  to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that the `target` property of your link is ignored as the javascript is submitting the form, you'd have to modify your `getMenuRequest` method to set the `form` target:

```
function getMenuRequest(actionName,methodName){
    document.forms[0].action=actionName+".htm";
    document.forms[0].method.value=methodName;
    document.forms[0].target='workFrame';
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

There is one caveat though, if you submit the form later on other requests, it would still have a target of `workFrame`, and may then target the wrong frame...

N.B. I haven't tried this...

Comment: this way takes the request to new tap in the broswer,

Comment: thanks for the post, it helped but with some limitation, as i have mentioned in the previous comment, Please help

Comment: :) Fixed that,I have given the target in the link which is getting generated in java, once i remove that it is working fine, thanks for the help